# segue table view to view controller and table view

Tags: iphone, ios

Sorry, i'm new in IOS development.

I have a table view with five cells.

1 cell will segue to table view and the other 4 cell will segue to view controller.

From the code below, cell "Attraction" will segue to table view and the other cell will segue to view controller.

How do i can do that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    mainMenu = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Introduction", @"History", @"Attractions", @"Culture", @"About", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [mainMenu count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"MainMenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [mainMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: either you use 2 prototype cells, one prototype segue to A, other prot segue to B (uisng storyboard), either by code @ didselectrowatindexpath, you do if(indexpath.row == 0){self.navcontroller pushview..:A ..} else {push B}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **static table view cells**. This is a setting for the table view in interface builder. This is feasible setup because you only have a fixed number of five cells.

If you still need dynamic cells, you cannot use interface builder to assign the segue to a specific cell. Instead, you have to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and perform the segue in code via `performSegueWithIdentifier`.